# Specified token is invalid or expired in Vtiger Login

Tags: android, vtiger

I have tried to Login Vtiger from my Android Application.I got Challenge token successfully and concodinate that challenge token with access key(taken from my account preferences). Then convert to MD5 string.

**My Challenge URL:**

```
http://mysite/vtigerCRM510-RC/vtigerCRM/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=Manager
```

**Challenge Response:**

```
{"success":true,"result":{"token":"4ff555f87eece","serverTime":1341478392,"expireTime":1341478692}}
```

**Login URL:**

```
http://mysite/vtigerCRM510-RC/vtigerCRM/webservice.php?operation=login&username=Manager&accesskey=976b9571ff3ff92b7786da17125ac37c
```

**Login Response:**

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN","message":"Specified token is invalid or expired"}}
```

Also I have a doubt, In Android I used AsyncTask for Http Operation.Two Asynctask used.Fisrt one for get Challenge token and using this token done  second Async task for Login. Is it correct way? My Android code is below.

**My Android Code:**

```
public class GetChallengeActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;
    private static final String USER_NAME="Manager";
    private static final String ACCESS_KEY="myaccesskey"; //taken from preferences

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void postData(View view)
    {
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttext);

        ConnectivityManager conmgr=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkinfo=conmgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        Log.i(null, "Network Info-->"+networkinfo.toString());
        if(networkinfo!=null && networkinfo.isConnected())
        {
            //Network Available.
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(null, "Network Available");
            textView.setText("Network Available");
            String url="http://mysite/vtigerCRM510-RC/vtigerCRM/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username="+USER_NAME+"";
            Log.i(null,"Challenge URL-->"+url);
            new ServerCommunication().execute(url);
        }
        else
        {
            //Network not Available
            Log.i(null, "Network Not Available");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setText("Network Not Available");
        }
    }

    private class ServerCommunication extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Log.i(null, "Doing in Background");
            try {
                return postToServer(urls[0]);
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(null, "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.");
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Log.i(null, "onPostExecute");
            Log.i(null, result);
            textView.setText(result);
        }

        private String postToServer(String string) throws IOException{
            Log.i(null, "post2Server");
            InputStream is = null;
            // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved web page content.
            int len = 500;

            try {
                    URL url = new URL(string);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                    is = conn.getInputStream();

                    // Convert the InputStream into a string
                    String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
                    Log.i(null,contentAsString);

                   String result="";
                    try {
                            JSONObject jsondata=new JSONObject(contentAsString);

                            String outcomesrf=jsondata.getString("success");
                            Log.i(null, "OutCome---->"+outcomesrf);
                            if(outcomesrf=="false")
                            {
                                JSONObject jsonobj2=jsondata.getJSONObject("error");
                                result=jsonobj2.getString("message");
                                Log.i(null,"Error-->errorMessage---->"+result);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                JSONObject jsonobj3=jsondata.getJSONObject("result");
                                result=jsonobj3.getString("token");
                                Log.i(null,"Success-->Token---->"+result);
                                Log.i(null,"-->MD5Hash("+result+ACCESS_KEY+")");
                                String generatedkey=MD5_Hash(result+ACCESS_KEY);
                                Log.i(null,"Key-->"+generatedkey);
                                String loginurl="http://mysite/vtigerCRM510-RC/vtigerCRM/webservice.php?operation=login&username="+USER_NAME+"&accesskey="+generatedkey+"";
                                Log.i(null,"Login URL-->"+loginurl);
                                new LoginCommunication().execute(loginurl);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i(null,"At Json "+e.toString());
                        }
                    return result;
                }
            finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    } 
                }
        }

        // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.

    }

    private class LoginCommunication extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                Log.i(null, "Login Posting in Background");
                try {
                    return loginToServer(urls[0]);
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(null, "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.");
                    return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
               }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
                Log.i(null, "LoginonPostExecute");
                Log.i(null, result);
                textView.setText(result);
            }

             private String loginToServer(String string) throws IOException{
                Log.i(null, "loginToServer");
                InputStream is = null;
                int len = 500;

                try {
                        URL url = new URL(string);
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);

                        // Starts the query
                        conn.connect();
                        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                        is = conn.getInputStream();

                        // Convert the InputStream into a string
                        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
                        Log.i(null,contentAsString);

                       String result1="";
                       String result2="";

                        try {
                                JSONObject jsondata=new JSONObject(contentAsString);

                                String outcomesrf=jsondata.getString("success");
                                Log.i(null, "Login OutCome---->"+outcomesrf);
                                if(outcomesrf=="false")
                                {
                                    JSONObject jsonobj2=jsondata.getJSONObject("error");
                                    result1=jsonobj2.getString("message");
                                    Log.i(null,"Error-->errorMessage---->"+result1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    JSONObject jsonobj3=jsondata.getJSONObject("result");
                                    result1=jsonobj3.getString("sessionName");
                                    Log.i(null,"Success-->sessionName---->"+result1);

                                    JSONObject jsonobj4=jsondata.getJSONObject("result");
                                    result2=jsonobj4.getString("userId");
                                    Log.i(null,"Success-->userId---->"+result2);

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.i(null,"At Json "+e.toString());
                            }
                        String result="sessionName"+result1+" userId"+result2;
                        return result;
                    }
                finally {
                        if (is != null) {
                            is.close();
                        } 
                    }
            }
        }

        public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
            char[] buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }

        public static String MD5_Hash(String s) {
            MessageDigest m = null;

            try {
                    m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            m.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
            String hash = new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);
            return hash;
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Ramprasad I'm creating a simple app to show only leads from the crm server. I don't find any proper documentation on how to make the login activity properly. If I've to login only using the accessKey then how should I login using the username password? official vtiger crm clients and others have username and passowrd logins. I'm confused to proceed further. could you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PostToServer, the accesskey verb should be with a upper k (accessKey)

```
String loginurl="http://mysite/vtigerCRM510-RC/vtigerCRM/webservice.php?operation=login&username="+USER_NAME+"&accessKey="+generatedkey+"";
```

Comment: Hi @GbillyB I'm creating a simple app to show only leads from the crm server. I don't find any proper documentation on how to make the login activity properly. If I've to login only using the accessKey then how should I login using the username password? official vtiger crm clients and others have username and passowrd logins. I'm confused to proceed further. could you please help me